# PostGIS - Sort Proximity Results Into Groups Based on Distance from Center

Tags: postgis, proximity

The scenario is as follows: I have a database of pizza places with review averages. I want users to be able to find pizza places near a location and have them sorted by distance. Pretty straight forward. Instead of strictly sorting by distance, I also wanted to sort by the review average, but only in groups--say, every 15 miles. This way, they'd get results close to them, but the best places would be pushed to the top of each distance group. My initial thought was round each result to the nearest 15 mile increment and sort on that result, and secondarily, by the review average:

```
select p.*, floor((ST_Distance(p.geom, ST_GeomFromText('CENTER_POINT_HERE', 4326), true) / 1609.34) / 15) * 15 as distance
from geo_test p
where ST_DWithin(p.geom, ST_GeomFromText('CENTER_POINT_HERE', 4326), SEARCH_RADIUS_HERE)
order by distance asc, rating_average desc
```

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a grid, and within each grid cell, find  all pizza places within 15 miles, sorted by review?

Comment: I'm not sure about a grid--could you explain more? Basically, I want the results sorted for every 15-mile group. So, say the search radius is 45 miles; you'd have 3 groups, sorted by the group distance, so 15, 30, 45. Within each group, each individual restaurant would be sorted by highest rating first.